# Using 'r+' mode to overwrite a line in a file with another line of the same length

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file called `vegetables`:

> carrots
>   apples_
>   cucumbers

What I want to do is open the file in python, and modify it in-place, without overwriting large portions of the file. Specifically, I want to overwrite `apples_` with `lettuce`, such that the file would look like this:

> carrots
>   lettuce
>   cucumbers

To do this, I've been told to use `'r+'` mode. However, I don't know how to overwrite that line in place. Is that possible? All the solutions I am familiar with involve caching the entire file, and then overwriting the entire file, for a small amendment. Is this really the best option?

**Important note**: the replacement line is always the same length as the original line.

For context: I'm not really concerned with a file on vegetables. Rather, I have a textfile of about 400 lines to which I need to make revisions roughly every two minutes. I have a script to do this, but I want to do it more efficiently.

Comment: Does the replacement line always have exactly the same length as the original line?

Comment: @Npe Yes (15characterlimit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an answer that works with your example

```
with open("vegetables","r+") as t:
  data = t.read()
  t.seek(data.index("apples_"))
  t.write("lettuce")
```

although, it might not be worth it to complicate things like this,

it's fine to just read the entire file, and then overwriting the entire file, you aren't going to save much by doing something like my example

NOTE: this only works if it has the exactly the same length as the original text you are replacing

edit1: a (possibly bad) example to replace all match:

```
import re

with open("test","r+") as t:
  data = t.read()
  for m in re.finditer("apples_", data):
    t.seek(m.start())
    t.write("lettuce")
```

edit2: something a little more complex using closure so that it can check for multiple words to replace

```
import re

def get_find_and_replace(f):
    """f --> a file that is open with r+ mode"""
    data = f.read()
    def find_and_replace(old, new):
        for m in re.finditer(old, data):
            f.seek(m.start())
            f.write(new)
    return find_and_replace

with open("test","r+") as f:
  find_and_replace = get_find_and_replace(f)
  find_and_replace("apples_","lettuce")
  #find_and_replace(...,...)
  #find_and_replace(...,...)
```

Comment: what if there are two lines with `apples_`?

Comment: I know the question is tagged python-2.7, but it's worth noting that this will not work in quite the same way with text files in Python 3, since the relationship between character count (from `index`) and file position (for `t.seek`) is not guaranteed (officially you should only call `seek` on a text file using a value from `tell`). You could make it work using binary files, but then you'd have to manually encode the strings you were substituting if they were Unicode (and you'd need to verify that the encoded versions of the strings were the same length, rather than the Unicode versions).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it most likely wouldn't work as expected, but all the answer currently doesn't work if the string isn't unique

Comment: fileinput will still work, what i meant was unique as in not a substring of another string, fileinput will work for a million identical lines

Comment: @Blckknght that's true, although it does work on python 3 for the example that OP has given

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the fileinput answer didn't really answer the question, it just print the file with the string replace, not overwrite part of the file as requested by OP

Comment: @freeforalltousez, do you know what fileinput actually does? It does exactly what your code is doing, difference is it will work for multiple replacements

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, my bad, the print is very misleading, although running replace for every line isn't really efficient, but does it really only overwrite the part that has change and not every line?

Comment: considering there are max 15 chars I think it is not so bad,  fileinput.input has the inplace flag for a reason, it is the only solution that will work for multiple replacements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64561/discussion-between-freeforall-tousez-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

If I understanding you correctly [fileinput.input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) should work providing the string is not a substring of another:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("in.txt",inplace=True):
    print(line.rstrip().replace("apples_","lettuce"))
```

`print(line.rstrip().replace("apples_","lettuce"))` actually **writes** to the file **inplace**  it does **not** print the line.

you can also check for multiple words to replace in one pass:

```
old = "apples_"
for line in fileinput.input("in.txt",inplace=True):
    if line.rstrip() == old:
        print(line.rstrip().replace(old,"lettuce"))
    elif ....
    elif....
    else:
        print(line.rstrip())
```