# Can not write content in file

Tags: python, fwrite

```
path = "/work/Bible" 
files= os.listdir(path)
txt = []
for file in files: 
    position =path+ '//' + file
    print (position)         
    with open(position,"r+",encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f: 
            old_str = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
            for i in range(0,len(old_str)):
                line = line.replace(old_str[i],"\n"+"###### v"+old_str[i],1)
            f.write(line)
```

I was going to add ####### before all the numbers in the text, but nothing happens when the last step writes to the original text. This question may be very beginner, but it bothers me, and I would appreciate the help.

Comment: With `r+` mode, the first write will overwrite the rest of the file. You want to read through to the end of the file, then rewind the file (or simply close and reopen for writing) and write out the modified contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823460/using-r-mode-to-overwrite-a-line-in-a-file-with-another-line-of-the-same-leng