# Python method file.write() writes at wrong location after file.read()

Tags: python, file-io

If I read partway through a file in Python (version 3.11.2 running on Windows 10 Home version 22H2) and then write to the file, I expected it would write at the location I was up to (like it does if I read again from the file), but instead it writes to the end of the file. Is this the intended behaviour of Python's built-in `write()` method or is it a bug? I get the same results when running Python (version 3.11.2) on MacOS (version 12.6.3).

I have a file `content.txt` containing the following text:
`this is just some miscellaneous unimportant text`

Code:

```
with open("content.txt", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    print("start tell", file.tell())

    a = file.read(20)
    a_tell = file.tell()
    print(f"{a=} {a_tell=}")

    b = file.read(5)
    b_tell = file.tell()
    print(f"{b=} {b_tell=}")

    file.write("ABCDE")
    abcde_tell = file.tell()
    print(f"{abcde_tell=}")

    file.seek(b_tell)
    print("seek b_tell", file.tell())

    file.write("XYZ")
    xyz_tell = file.tell()
    print(f"{xyz_tell=}")
```

Output:

```
start tell 0
a='this is just some mi' a_tell=20
b='scell' b_tell=25
abcde_tell=53
seek b_tell 25
xyz_tell=28
```

After running my code I expected to `content.txt` to contain:
`this is just some miscellXYZDEs unimportant text`
but instead I got
`this is just some miscellXYZous unimportant textABCDE`

From these results it seems that `file.read(n)` followed by:

- `file.read(m)` will read from position n
- `file.write("ABCDE")` will write at the end of the file, not at position n, which to me is unintuitive
- `file.seek(n)` and then `file.write("XYZ")` will write at position n (as expected)

Why does `file.read(n)` followed by `file.write("ABCDE")` write to the end of the file rather at position n? Is this the intended behaviour of Python's built-in `write()` method or is it a bug?

Comment: You can use fileinput to replace contents of a file.

Comment: I don't think that's a valid duplicate. Probably a better one is the one which says "don't use `'r+'` mode; it doesn't do what you expect".

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823460/using-r-mode-to-overwrite-a-line-in-a-file-with-another-line-of-the-same-leng (not the one I wanted to find, but seems good enough).

Comment: I thought there is only one file pointer aka "position" in a file. How can the reading position be different from the writing position?

Comment: In so many words, writing in this mode automatically moves the file pointer.